# Self-written facts in Prolog?

Tags: reflection, prolog

How can you write code in Prolog that generates facts in response to the input of the user without you writing them by hand?

For example, i give the input:

Johnny loves Sally.
Karen loves Bob.

The program should respond by creating the facts

```
loves(Johnny, Sally).
loves(Karen, Bob).
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `assertz` and friends.

Comment: Your facts would have to be `loves(john, sally).` or `loves('John', 'Sally').` to be valid atoms (capitalized identifiers are variables).

Comment: Why not write down the facts as Prolog code? Processing free-format natural language may turn out harder than you think...

Answer (score 0):

Of course you'd need to write a parser for the input examples you're showing, then translate those into facts you can assert with `assertz` as @EugeneSh. has indicated.

Let's say you've parsed your input and you have the "verb" or predicate identifier in a variable, `Verb`, and you have the arguments in a list, `Args`. Then you can do it like this:

```
Fact =.. [Verb | Args],
assertz( Fact ).
```

The `=../2` operator corresponds a term with a list. For example:

```
| ?- foo(a, b) =.. L.

L = [foo,a,b]

yes
| ?- Term =.. [foo, x, y].

Term = foo(x,y)

yes
| ?-
```

As I mentioned in my comment, you need to make sure that your predicate identifier as well as your arguments are grounded terms (do not contain variables) if you want these as specific facts. An atom needs to start with a lower case letter, or you have to put it in single quotes. Valid atoms: `foo`, `bAr`, `'Sam'`. The following are variables: `FOO`, `Sam`.